# Fixed pop up for scrollable elements displays where an element is at the moment

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I didn't find the right answer to my question.

using Angular, I'm displaying file names in a scrollable div. I need to hover over a file name and see some info in a pop up.

The problem is that pop up shows based on where file name was positioned before user started scrolling. I.e. if I scroll all the way down and hover over a filename, pop up will be displayed somewhere on the bottom of the page.

Another detail is that right after a scrollable div I have a non-scrollable div. I think because of that I can't use position absolute because pop up won't be rendered on top of the second component.

```
  <div style="display:table;" class="upload-item" *ngFor="let f of files; let i = index;">
    <span class="filenameblock">
        <span class="file-name">{{ f.name}</span>
        <span class="tooltiptext">{{f.info}}</span>
    </span>

    <span style="width:30%;" class="progress">
        <span class="bar" [style.width]="f?.progress?.data?.percentage + '%'"></span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>Non scrollable div here</div>
```

css:

```
.upload-items .upload-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 5vh;
  line-height: 4.9vh;
  border: 2px solid #CBCBCB;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.filenameblock {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
  color: #74809D;
  margin-left: 5px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  background-color: #E7F5FC;
  color: #6A6A6A;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  left: 10vw;
  margin-top: 3vw;
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: 1000;*/
}

 .file-name:hover + .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
 }
```

I tried to add 'top' to pop up styling but in this case pop up displayed on the same height all the time. 
[image]

Comment: You will need `position: absolute;` instead of `position: fixed;` since the latter relates to the viewport, not its parent element

Comment: For one thing, your tooltip has position: fixed, the parent seems relative and I'm not sure what the rest of the page looks like, this is a simple matter of positioning. If you want a modal-like behavior though, perhaps create a modal-like component? So not as child here but as a service bound singleton somewhere outside of your scrollable list?